# iFrame contents are returned undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to work on iFrame contents and the below snippet is not returning the value of `h1` from the iFramed URL. Instead, it alerts `undefined`. Can someone please suggest what is wrong here?

```
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="myBtn">Login</button>
<br><br>
<iframe name="SSOBlock" id="SSOBlock" src="https://www.example.com/" ></iframe>

<script>

$("#myBtn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($('iframe[name=SSOBlock]').contents().find('h1').html());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't access iframe contents if it's in a different domain than the page.

Comment: That domain don't actually has the header X-Frame-Options. Still can't we access?

Comment: No. It's blocked by default, X-Frame-Options is irrelevant.